# How do I use REGTLIB.EXE to unregister a type library

Tags: regtlib

How do I use `REGTLIB.EXE` to unregister a type library?

Is this even possible? When I type `regtlib /?` it displays no information at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

`regtlib -u [filename]`

Background:

There are (at least) two versions of `regtlib.exe`. Since at least version 6.0.81.91 (having file size is 40960) it DOES support `-u` to unregister a `.TLB`
file.

The version that does not support `-u` has no version information, which 
means that when you view its properties in Windows explorer, there is no 
version tab. And the file length is 30720 bytes.

([Original forum post / notes](http://computer-programming-forum.com/64-vb-com/588d2507d4abe793.htm))